# How to write a nested if statement within a Do-While Loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, do-while

I am a beginner Java student. This is the general idea of what I'm doing.

I have a list of things that a user can pick from by inputting the corresponding number.  After they input ONE integer, the string next to the item prints as `YES`.  If they decide they don't want it anymore, they have to input that same number again and then string is supposed to change to `NO`. My nested loop technique is allowing for this change, but changes it right back after reading the next if statement.  I have been working on this for a very long time.  Can anyone please nudge me in the right direction to identify this problem?

```
     do
    {
        int num=input.nextInt();  

        if (num == 7)
        {               
            if(s.equals("NO"))  //corresponding string
            {
               s = "YES";
            }
            if(s.equals("YES"))  //same corresponding string
            {
               s = "NO";
            }
        }

    //similar if statements for different conditions 
    //similar if statements for different conditions 


    }while(myBoolean()==true);
```

Comment: Use an else if block. `if (something) {...} else if (something else) {...}` Your code is missing the `else` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 do
{
```

Just add the word "else" in between your "if" statements. In your example, when s is "NO", you change it to "YES". Therefore s is "YES" when you hit your second "if" statement.

Better yet, instead of testing for both values "YES and "NO", just test for one of them and assume the opposite case if the test fails.

E.g.:
     do
    {
        int num=input.nextInt();

```
    if (num == 7)
    {               
        if(s.equals("NO"))  //corresponding string
        {
           s = "YES";
        }
        else  // <--- This is the only change I made.
        {
           s = "NO";
        }
    }

//similar if statements for different conditions 
//similar if statements for different conditions 


}while(myBoolean()==true);
```

Comment: wow that was so simple! thank you very much! but now for some reason i have to input a number twice before it loops again...do you think something is wrong with my boolean?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing an else statement.

```
if(s.equals("NO"))  //corresponding string
{
   s = "YES";
} else if(s.equals("YES"))  //same corresponding string
{
   s = "NO";
}
```

or if you want to shorten things a bit:

```
s = s.equalsIgnoreCase("NO") ? "YES" : "NO";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use an `else if` statement like so

```
if (num == 7)
{               
    if(s.equals("NO"))
    {
       s = "YES";
    }
    else if(s.equals("YES"))
    {
       s = "NO";
    }
}
```

If the first `if` statement is `true`, it will skip the `else if` statement. If the `if` statement is `false`, it will read the `else if` statement. You can also have multiple `else if` statements like so

```
if(boolean)
{
   ....
}
else if(another boolean)
{
   ....
}
else if(some other boolean)
{
   ....
}
```

If the `if` statement and all `else if` statements are `false`, you can add an `else` statement, which will be read

```
if(boolean)
{
   ....
}
else if(another boolean)
{
   ....
}
else
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  The problem now is that it works for changing it from yes to no, but then I can't change it back to yes again without restarting the program